# Display tooltip when hovering over paypal button?

Tags: button, paypal, tooltip, title, alt

I have tried using alt and title attributes in the `<div>` surrounding the code, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'd like to give potential buyers some reassurance about the price without them having to login to paypal or even click the button. Surely there must be a way to get this to work? It has to be an official browser tooltip though, because it has to be trustworthy.

Here is the standard paypal code these days:

```
    <div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=clientID&enable-funding=venmo&currency=AUD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'pill',
          color: 'silver',
          layout: 'horizontal',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"description":"test","amount":{"currency_code":"AUD","value":100}}]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            
            // Full available details
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));

            // Show a success message within this page, e.g.
            const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';

            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to give potential buyers some reassurance about the price without them having to login to paypal or even click the button.

The only solution is to display the price/description in a DOM element
(separate `<div>` or similar) next to the paypal button container.

So, something like:

```html
    <div id="smart-button-container">
      <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>Test A$100</h2>
        <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or whatever styling and positioning fits your page.

Comment: Are you sure there is no way of accomplishing this?
It's not a case of unknown unknowns?

Comment: The contents of the paypal button container are not guaranteed and subject to change at any time. You can/should only insert your own additional content outside that container.

Comment: Can? Should? If there's a way to do it I would like to know. That's my <div> on a server that I'm paying for. And paypal is getting my commission. I want to do it to remove ambiguity, not to trick people.

Comment: See the answer for what you should do.

Comment: But I don't want to display the price in h2 (or any other h).
If I had've wanted that I would've asked for it.
It's going to completely ruin the aesthetic design aspect of it.

Comment: It is an example. Use a different element and style and layout that suits.